# Laravel POST Dropzone Programmatically

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I have created a div: `<div id="avatar" background-image:url('/avatar.png')">`

I also used jQuery

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("div#avatar").dropzone({ url: "{{ url('/avatar')}}"});
   });
```

It was working but I was receiving TokenMismatchError, so I added this code too:

```
Dropzone.options.avatar = {
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append("_token", "{{{ csrf_token() }}}");  
   }
 };
```

When I view:source, I can see the token but when I post, I still get a TokenMismatchError.

*View-source:*

```
formData.append("_token", "ra4yjV9WclT6uwQn2KsuPdHjS4T2cDAWAvRDfpbR");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the options when programatically generating Dropzone:

```
 $("div#avatar").dropzone({ url: "{{ url('/avatar')}}",
     sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
         formData.append("_token", "{{{ csrf_token() }}}");
 }});
```